# Auto-close foundation alert

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Hello so currently I have this zurb-foundation code which just shows alert and can be closed by clicking the x link.

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">
    <p> Sorry, your account is banned. Please go to the admin to fix the issue. </p>
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do is instead of clicking the x link, I want it to auto-close every x number of seconds. Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

so I've managed to do my own trick. This works

```
$('.alert-box').closest('[data-alert]').fadeOut(3500);
```